# ¿como puedo hacer para que los valores almacenados en una funcion ingresen en otra?

Tags: c++, funciones

Tengo que hacer que los valores retornados de mi primera función entren en la 2da función para que esta me de un resultado.

Este es el problema:

Escribe un subproceso llamado perímetroCaja(ancho, largo) que reciba 2 parámetros, ancho y largo y que retorne el perímetro de un rectángulo.

Escribe un subproceso llamado leerDatos(ancho, largo) que utilice 2 parámetros por referencia para guardar el valor de ancho y largo pedidos desde el teclado.

Escribe un proceso principal donde se ejecuten los 2 subprocesos: ejecutar primero leerDatos() y después perimetroCaja(). Escribir el valor del perímetro en el proceso principal.

Esto es el código que llevo:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int leerdatos(int, int);

int perimetrocaja(int, int);

int main(){

    int ancho,largo, perimetro;
    
    leerdatos(ancho,largo);
    
    perimetrocaja(ancho,largo);
    
    cout<<"El perimetro del rectangulo es: "<<perimetro;
    
    return 0;
}

int leerdatos(int ancho, int largo){

    cout<<"Ingrese el ancho del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>ancho;
    cout<<"Ingrese el largo del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>largo;
    
    return ancho, largo;
}

int perimetrocaja(int ancho,int largo){
    
    int perimetro=0;

    perimetro=(ancho*ancho)+(largo*largo);
    
    return perimetro;
}
```

Creo que el problema puede estar en los valores que retorna la primera función y aparte que no se como hacer que los valores que se retornen ingresen en la 2da función, de antemano agradezco los consejos que puedan ofrecerme.

Comment: *"leerDatos(ancho, largo) que utilice 2 parámetros por referencia"*. Leer bien las instrucciones que te dieron es importante. Te dicen que pases los parámetros por referencia, y tu los estas pasando por copia. Si los pasas por copia, el `ancho` y `largo` que tienes en tu `main` nuca se verán afectados. Y al hacer solo `perimetrocaja(ancho,largo);` estas descartando el valor de retorno de tu función, tiene que ser `perimetro = perimetrocaja(ancho,largo);`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede en tu función:

```
int leerdatos(int ancho, int largo){

    cout<<"Ingrese el ancho del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>ancho;
    cout<<"Ingrese el largo del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>largo;
    
    return ancho, largo;
}
```

Es que haces uso del operador coma. Este operador lo que hace es evaluar varias operaciones secuenciales y devolver el resultado de la última.

En tu caso el código equivalente sería:

```
int leerdatos(int ancho, int largo){

    cout<<"Ingrese el ancho del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>ancho;
    cout<<"Ingrese el largo del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>largo;
    
    ancho;
    return largo;
}
```

Como ves, el código así se ve algo absurdo, ya que la instrucción `ancho;` no hace nada útil.

Piensa que en tu caso has indicado que la función retorna `int`, luego únicamente podrá devolver un entero, no dos ni tres ni ... solo uno. Cualquier intento por devolver otra cosa (y siempre que esa *cosa* no pueda ser convertido a `int`), generará un mensaje de error al compilar. Por ejemplo:

```
return "abcde"; // ERROR
```

Para retornar más de un valor puedes usar una pareja (2 valores) o una tupla (todos los que quieras):

```
std::pair<int, int> leerdatos()
{
    cout<<"Ingrese el ancho del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>ancho;
    cout<<"Ingrese el largo del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>largo;

    return {ancho, largo}; // C++11
    return std::make_pair(ancho, largo); // Versiones anteriores de C++
}
```

Ahora los dos valores viajan en una misma variable. Para separarlos puedes hacerlo de varias maneras:

```
// Version tradicional
std::pair<int, int> pareja = leerdatos();
int ancho = pareja.first;
int largo = pareja.second;

// C++11
int ancho, largo;
std::tie(ancho, largo) = leerdatos();

// C++17
auto [ancho, largo] = leerdatos();
```

Aunque lo que te están pidiendo en el ejercicio es que uses parámetros como referencias, es decir:

```
void leerdatos(int & ancho, int & largo)
{
    cout<<"Ingrese el ancho del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>ancho;
    cout<<"Ingrese el largo del rectangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>largo;  
}
```

Si no usas las referencias `&` entonces no podrás modificar las variables de `main`, ya que entonces `leerdatos` recibirá una copia de las mismas (Si tu clonas una oveja y matas al clon -o al original- el otro animal seguirá vivo misteriosamente, ¿cierto?).

**NOTA FINAL**: Tu programa tiene dos errores más:

- no estás modificando en ningún sitio la variable `perimetro` del main
- tu fórmula para calcular el perímetro es, cuanto menos, discutible. El perímetro usa unidades de longitud. Multiplicar dos dimensiones (o una unidad por si misma) ya te está dando un área.

Answer (score 0):

Mira, hasta donde yo se no puedes retornar ambos valores de tu función leerdatos, es por eso que te arroja valores basura, la opcion que te doy es que llames a la funcion para obterner ancho y largo respectivamente, de la siguiente manera:

```
int leerdatos(int, string);

int perimetrocaja(int, int);

int main(){

    int ancho,largo=5, perimetro;
    
    ancho = leerdatos(ancho, "ancho");
    largo = leerdatos(largo, "largo");
    
    perimetro = perimetrocaja(ancho,largo);
    
    cout<<"El perimetro del rectangulo es: "<<perimetro;
    
    return 0;
}

int leerdatos(int x, string frase){

    cout<<"Ingrese el "<<frase<< " del rectangulo :"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    
    return x;
}

int perimetrocaja(int ancho,int largo){
    
    int perimetro;
    perimetro =  (ancho*ancho)+(largo*largo) ;
    return perimetro;

    
}
```